# Transferring cookies from site to another site

Tags: cookies

Is it possible to create a cookie from a first site on the user's browser and remains even if he goes to visit a second site. ( define it as a uid )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you were able to do that there would be huge potential for exploitation.

Cookies are locked down to specific URLs and can only be used on there. A global cookie would be terrible practice as you would be able to alter a user's cookies outside of those defined and used on your own site.

I'm not sure why you would want to do this anyway as there is absolutely no reason to do so. If you want to share a cookie with another site you have, then that is entirely possible by making that user send a request to your site and then giving them a specific cookie upon the request. Unless you have malicious intent, there would be no reason or use for global cookies.